# GTMetrix Not Picking Up CDN

Tags: cdn, gtmetrix

How do I get GTMetrix to show my CDN? We are using WP Engine and I have gone into 'user settings' under my account and added both (as i'm not sure which is technically correct) for 'YSlow CDN Hostnames':

WP Engine

wpengine

And neither are working. It still shows as F(0).

Another site I am working on also uses Shopify's CDN and that too isn't showing, even with 'Shopify' in the list.

I searched around but could not find an answer. Has anyone succeeded with this?

Answer (score 0):

It should be an hostname (subdomain + domain name), 1 per line:

Example:

[image: CDN Hostnames]

Comment: Thanks. I put cdn.shopify.com and cdn.wpengine.com (separate lines) and it still didn't work...

Comment: Probably a problem on GTMetrix website then, that's working for me. I guess you can still validate the answer :)